# Stokes' Theorem: surface integral over the lateral surface of a pyramid

Tags: surface-integrals, line-integrals, stokes-theorem

> Let $S$ be the lateral surface of the pyramid with points $(0,0,0)$, $(1,3,0)$,  $(1,3,5)$ and $(0,3,0)$ as shown:
>   [image: pyramid]
>   Let $\mathbf{F}(x,y,z)=(y,2x,xyz)$ be a vector field.
>   Evaluate the surface integral $$\iint_S \operatorname{curl}( \mathbf{F} ) \cdot \mathbf{n} \,ds $$
>   Answer: $3/2$

I parametrized the plane that the triangle is laying and found $\operatorname{curl}(\mathbf{F})$. The problem is the domain of integration of the suface integral. If you have a better way to solve the problem, please be my guest.

Comment: How about using the Stoke's theorem you are mentioning? .

Comment: I edited the question to explain better.

Comment: The Stoke's theorem lets you evaluate a line integral instead of the surface integral. Or in other words it says they are equal, and the line integral is in many cases easier to calculate. If you have parametrized the triangle already, then it's just a matter of calculating the line integral.

Comment: I did not parametrized the triangle, I parametrized the plane that the triangle is laying. I don't know how I can found the domain of that region.

Comment: If you are talking about the side laying in the x-y plane, its a straightforward matter to parameterize the lines making up the sides of the triangle. You have several points that can be used to make up equations for these lines. For instance the line connecting $(0,0,0)$ and $(1,3,0)$ can be parameterized by $x=t, y=3t, z=0$. Or you can parameterize them in terms of each other. $y = 3x$ for instance, so that the range of integration is $\int_0^1 \int_{3x}^{3} (\dots) dy dx$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the downwards oriented base triangle $T$ to your surface $S$to obtain the boundary surface $\partial P$ of the pyramid. Gauss' divergence theorem then gives
$$\int_S{\rm curl}({\bf F})\cdot{\bf n}\>{\rm d}\omega+\int_T{\rm curl}({\bf F})\cdot{\bf n}\>{\rm d}\omega=\int_{\partial P}{\rm curl}({\bf F})\cdot{\bf n}\>{\rm d}\omega=\int_P{\rm div}\bigl({\rm curl}({\bf F})\bigr)\>{\rm dvol}=0\ ,$$
since ${\rm div}\bigl({\rm curl}({\bf F})\bigr)\equiv0$. It follows that
$$\int_S{\rm curl}({\bf F})\cdot{\bf n}\>{\rm d}\omega=-\int_T{\rm curl}({\bf F})\cdot{\bf n}\>{\rm d}\omega=-\int_T (c_1,c_2,c_3)\cdot(0,0,-1)\>{\rm d}\omega\ .$$
Since $c_3=F_{2.1}-F_{1.2}=1$ we obtain as final result the area of $T$, which is $={\displaystyle{3\over2}}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Let $S_1$ be the triangle $(0,0,0)$, $(1,3,0)$, $(1,3,5)$ [it's analogous for others faces]. Applying Stokes theorem, we get
$$\int_{S_1} {\rm curl}({\bf F})\cdot {\bf n} \, {\rm d}s = \oint_{\partial S_1} {\bf F}(x) \, {\rm d}x.$$
Hence, you just have to look at the boundary of $S_1$.

---

Let's calculate  $\oint_{\partial S_1} {\bf F}(x) \, {\rm d}x$:

We can split the path $\partial S_1$ in three paths: $\gamma_1, \gamma_2, \gamma_3$. For $t\in[0,1]$, we take

$\gamma_1(t) = (t,3t,0)$

$\gamma_2(t) = (1,3,0) + (0,0,5t) = (1,3,5t)$

$\gamma_3(t) = (1,3,5) + (-t,-3t,-5t) = (1-t,3-3t,5-5t)$

and calculate the line integral:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\oint_{\partial S_1} {\bf F}(x) \, {\rm d}x
& = \sum_{i=1}^3 \int_{\gamma_i} {\bf F}(x)\,{\rm d}x \\
& = \sum_{i=1}^3 \int_0^1 {\bf F}(\gamma_i(t))\cdot \gamma'_i(t)\, {\rm d}t,
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

where

$$\int_0^1 {\bf F}(\gamma_1(t))\cdot\gamma'_1(t) \, {\rm d}t
= \int_0^1 9t \, {\rm d}t
= \frac{9}{2},$$

$$\int_0^1 {\bf F}(\gamma_2(t))\cdot\gamma'_2(t) \, {\rm d}t
= \int_0^1 75t \, {\rm d}t 
= \frac{75}{2}$$

and

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\int_0^1 {\bf F}(\gamma_3(t))\cdot\gamma'_3(t) \, {\rm d}t
& = \int_0^1 84t-84 \, {\rm d}t \\
& = \frac{84}{2} - 84
= -42.
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Then
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\int_{S_1} {\rm curl}({\bf F})\cdot {\bf n} \, {\rm d}s
& = \oint_{\partial S_1} {\bf F}(x)\, {\rm d}x \\
& = \frac{9}{2} + \frac{75}{2} - 42 \\
& = 0
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Comment: Please, read again, I just edited the question. Btw, I don't think what you just said is relevant.

Comment: "The problem is the limit of integration to the surface integral": it depends on your parametrization, can you show your work explicitly? "If you have a better way to solve the problem, please be my guest": I think my answer gives a better way to solve the problem.

Comment: Well, you did not explain what you did. The problem is the boundary, you kind of just gave me something I don't know what it is. For example, $dw$. With your anwear I don't know how to solve it yet. You just gave me the definition for the Stokes Theorem.

Comment: You mean I just do the line integral in the xy plane of the projection? I'll try that.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry for that, it was just a notation, I've just changed it. And yes, I meant you've to calculate the line integral over of $F$ over $\partial S$. Hope my edited answer help you

Comment: It gave me 3 here. I used $\alpha_1 (t)=(1-t,3,0)$, $\alpha_2 (t)=(0,3-3t,0)$ and $\alpha_3 (t)=(t,3t,0)$, with $0 \le t \le 1$.

Comment: I was doing the projection in the x-y plane. I think that's the mistake.

Comment: I've just edited one more time, now it's clear what you have to do.

Comment: Yes, I understood what you did. I was just trying to do the parametrization myself and I got all wrong I was trying to parametrize the projection at the plane x-y, z-x, but I think the correct way is as you did, not the projection, but the surface where it is.

Comment: Didn't work. I think I made something wrong.

Comment: I got $\oint_{\partial S} {\bf F}(x)\, {\rm d}x = 0$.

Comment: The answer is $3/2$

Comment: I just notice that you've changed what $S$ is. Actually, my surface $S$ is the triangle $(0,0,0)$, $(1,3,0)$, $(1,3,5)$.